# Why does Minecraft Forge throw "method <init>()V not found" while building Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-forge

I want to make a mod for Minecraft-1.16.1.

I've downloaded gradle-4.10.3-bin.zip from https://cowtransfer.com/s/d42bf22b23bc46 and forge-1.16.1-32.0.63-mdk from [https://files.minecraftforge.net/](https://files.minecraftforge.net),and IDEA starts building Gradle automatically.

I added

```
maven { url = 'https://download.mcbbs.net/maven' }
maven { url = 'http://gradle.otakusaikou.com/releases' }
maven { url = 'http://bmclapi2.bangbang93.com/maven'}
maven { url = 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/central' }
maven { url = 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter' }
maven { url = 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven' }
```

in build.gradle because gradle.org is too slow to visit or download.

But IDEA throws

> Cause:
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.AbstractArtifactRepository:
> method ()V not found soon.

I've retried for several times but the problem hasn't been resolved.

Do I need to download `gradle.zip` and `forge-mdk` again? Or do I just need to wait?

Comment: I am asking for a long time on other websites. But no one could resolve. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: All parts of gradle.org are hard to visit.It takes me five minutes to open,and I couldn't download anything from it(timed out).So I used mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to get Gradle from any other source. The Forge MDK will take care of it.

You should reinstall the MDK, following these steps.

1. Download the 1.16.1 MDK from the official Minecraft Forge website. [Direct link](https://adfoc.us/serve/sitelinks/?id=271228&url=https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.16.1-32.0.75/forge-1.16.1-32.0.75-mdk.zip)
2. Unzip the file to the directory you want it in.
3. Import a new project into Intellij, selecting the `build.gradle` file.
4. Following the directions in the `README.txt`, use the terminal to run `gradlew genIntellijRuns`, then once that's done `gradlew --refresh-dependencies`.

Step 4 might take a while, but it should finish eventually.